# Solving Polynomial Functions

Tags: polynomials

How would I code the solution to this problem?
Let P be a polynomial satisfying P(x + 1) + P(x − 1) = x^3

for all real numbers x. 
I am trying to find P(x)

Comment: I am trying to find P(x)

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant info. Also, what have your tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, I am not really experienced in using Mathematica but I tried using solve but that did not work.

Comment: This does it: `FullSimplify[RSolve[P[x + 1] + P[x - 1] == x^3, P[x], x], 
 x \[Element] Reals]`. You can set the arbitrary constants `C[1]` and `C[2]` to zero to get a real polynomial.